# Number of characters limitation for parameters passed in SSRS subreports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a report and it's subreports. When I run the report, I found the 'object reference not set' error. So I am googling for this problem, I found that it is because there is Number of characters limitation for parameters passed in SSRS subreports(exactly 8000 characters). But my subreport exactly needs to get over 8000 characters as parameter. How can I solve it?

Comment: What kind of parameter are you passing that is 8000+ characters?

Comment: Seriously, you need to break this down into some more stages if your process results in passing 8000 character parameters around.  That's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Please hide the parameter which you are passing to the sub report. This parameter also need to be set as default values, So that when you will run this report all the values will be popup in this parameter and passed to the subreport.
Just try it.